# python importlib can't find a module inside a daemon context

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-daemon, python-importlib

I've got a script that imports modules dynamically based on configuration.  I'm trying to implement a daemon context (using the `python-daemon` module) on the script, and it seems to be interfering with python's ability to find the modules in question.

Insite `mymodule/__init__.py` in `setup()` I do this:

```
load_modules(args, config, logger)

try:
    with daemon.DaemonContext(
            files_preserve = getLogfileHandlers(logger)
            ):
        main_loop(config)
```

I've got a call to `setup()` inside `mymodule/__main__.py` and I'm loading the whole thing this way:
`PYTHONPATH=. python -m mymodule`

This works fine, but a listening port that gets set up inside load_modules() is closed by the newly added daemon context, so I want to move that function call inside the daemon context like so:

```
try:
    with daemon.DaemonContext(
            files_preserve = getLogfileHandlers(logger)
            ):
        load_modules(args, config, logger)
        main_loop(config)
```

Modules are loaded inside `load_modules()` this way:

```
for mysubmodule in modules:
    try:        
        i = importlib.import_module("mymodule.{}".format(mysubmodule))
    except ImportError as err:
        logger.error("import of mymodule.{} failed: {}".format(
            mysubmodule, err))
```

With `load_modules()` outside the daemon context this works fine.  When I move it inside the daemon context it seems to be unable to find the modules it's looking for.  I get this:

```
import of mymodule.submodule failed: No module named submodule
```

It looks like some sort of namespace problem -- I note that the exception only refers to the submodule portion of the module name I try to import -- but I've compared everything I can think of inside and outside the daemon context, and I can't find the important difference.  `sys.path` is unchanged, the daemon context isn't clearing the environemnt, or chrooting.  The cwd changes to `/` of course, but that shouldn't have any effect on python's ability to find modules, since the absolute path to `.` appears in `sys.path`.

What am I missing here?

EDIT: I'm adding an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) to make the situation more clear.  The following three files create a module called "mymodule" that can be run from the command line as `PYTHONPATH=. python -m mymodule`.  There are two calls to `load_module()` in `__init__.py`, one commented out.  You can demonstrate the problem by swapping which one is commented.

***`mymodule/__main__.py`***

```
from mymodule import setup
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(setup())
```

***`mymodule/__init__.py`***

```
import daemon
import importlib
import logging

def main_loop():
    logger = logging.getLogger('loop')
    logger.debug("Code runs here.")

def load_module():
    logger = logging.getLogger('load_module')
    submodule = 'foo'
    try:
        i = importlib.import_module("mymodule.{}".format(submodule))
    except ImportError as e:
        logger.error("import of mymodule.{} failed: {}".format(
            submodule, e))

def setup_logging():
    logfile = 'mymodule.log'
    fh = logging.FileHandler(logfile)
    root_logger = logging.getLogger()
    root_logger.addHandler(fh)
    root_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

def get_logfile_handlers(logger):
    handlers = []
    for handler in logger.handlers:
        handlers.append(handler.stream.fileno())
    return handlers

def setup():
    setup_logging()
    logger = logging.getLogger()

    # load_module()
    with daemon.DaemonContext(
            files_preserve = get_logfile_handlers(logger)
            ):
        load_module()
        main_loop()
```

***`mymodule/foo.py`***

```
import logging

logger=logging.getLogger('foo')
logger.debug("Inside foo.py")
```

Answer (score 2):

I spent a good 4 hours trying to work this one out when I hit it in my own project. The clue is here:

> If the module being imported is supposed to be contained within a package then the second argument passed to `find_module()`, `__path__` on the parent package, is used as the source of paths.

(From https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#import)

Once you have successfully imported `mymodule`, python2 no longer uses `sys.path` to search for the submodules, it uses `sys.modules["mymodule"].__path__`. When you import `mymodule`, python2 unhelpfully sets its `__path__` to the *relative* directory it was stored in:

```
mymodule.__path__ = ['mymodule']
```

After daemonizing, python's CWD is set to `/` and the *only* place the import internals search for `mysubmodule` is in `/mymodule`.

I worked around this by using `os.chdir()` to change CWD back to the old dir after daemonizing:

```
oldcwd = os.getcwd()
with DaemonizeContext():
    os.chdir(oldcwd)
    # ... daemon things
```

Answer (score 0):

> This works fine, but a listening port that gets set up inside load_modules() is closed by the newly added daemon context, so

No.  `load_modules()` should load modules.  It should not open ports.

If you need to preserve a file or socket opened outside the context, pass it to `files_preserve`.  If possible, it is preferred to simply open files and such inside the context instead, as I suggest above.

Comment: Those modules all do different things.  Some happen to open files or open listening ports.   I've checked and the DaemonContext isn't putting me in a chroot .. it doesn't do that by default, andI pointed out in the question that is not happening.  I've compared as much of the environment as I can before and after opening the context, and the only difference I can find is that CWD changes to /.   Run the sscce and you can check.

Comment: "Those modules all do different things. Some happen to open files or open listening ports." -- If they do that as an import-time side-effect, they're poorly designed and you should fix them.  Write a function you can call separately to open the ports/files when you need them.

Comment: Also, if it's not putting you in a chroot, what on Earth is the `files_preserve` argument doing?

Comment: That is what I am doing.  I'm just not demonstrating that in the SSCCE, because it's irrelevant to the question at hand, which is that loading modules breaks inside the daemon context.

Comment: Don't daemonize until your setup is complete.  Import everything first.

Comment: You should read the documentation on the daemon module, perhaps.  The standard process for daemonizing closes all open file handles.  files_preserve is used to prevent that for certain file handles .. in this case, open log files.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75116/discussion-between-kevin-and-mpounsett).

Comment: Further to your edit.. I am trying to open files and sockets inside the context as much as possible.  That is not the problem.  The problem is the interference with module loading.

Comment: "That is not the problem."  -- Then what is?  "The problem is the interference with module loading." -- [Nope, that's not it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: You're fixated on the wrong thing.  You keep telling me to open sockets and files inside the context, which I've said I'm already doing.

Comment: If you were already doing that (and using `files_preserve`), you would not need to load modules inside the daemon context.  Unless there is some *other* problem you're not telling us about.  Please explain that problem.

Comment: The XY Problem describes a situation where someone asks "how do I do X" where X is meaningless or nonsensical.  By contrast, I have here a very specific chunk of code that does not appear to work as expected.  Likely responses to the question are "That's expected behaviour because.."; "You forgot to do ... first."; or possibly even "You found a bug."  "You're asking the wrong question," isn't one of them.

Comment: You are not asking how to solve a problem.  You are asking how to *do a thing*.  If you won't provide context for why you want to do that thing, people will not be able to help you with it.  Your boss did not hand you a requirement specification saying "import modules after daemonizing."  You *chose* to use that approach in order to solve another problem.  Now you're refusing to discuss that other problem, and I simply can't help you any further.